# Mysql Select + C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Делаю авторизацию через базу данных через  MySql.Data на c#.

Есть таблица (id,name,surname)

Возможно ли запросом вытащить из базы данных name и surname зная id пользователя?

Comment: А в чем сложность то, вы не знаете как написать `select  name, surname from table where id=X` ?

Comment: Ответ - конечно возможно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если же просто `SQL` запрос надо сделать:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Id == 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

На то он и уникально, наше поле поле Id.

Person person = new db.Persons.Where(person => personId == 5);
// Лямбда выражение, я получу из таблицы персон человека с уникальным идентификатором, который равен 5.